# Wordpress edit css for the whole theme

Tags: css, wordpress

I have WordPress Multi site installed and all the same sites are using one theme. I changed a css file of the main site hoping to change even all the other sites installed under the main site but nothing is changing. The main site is changing but the other sites are not changing How can I make the css apply to all other sites?

Comment: But he says that the sites use the same theme. In Wordpress MU there will only be one copy of each theme for the entire network, so there should not be any difference between the CSS on the various sites using that theme. In fact, I don't even think you can say that you're changing the CSS of "the main site" because the theme is simply not linked to any specific site. Perhaps browser cache issues cause you not to see the changes?

Comment: Changing the theme CSS should affect all sites. Do you have a caching plugin installed and running? (WP Super Cache, WP Total Cache, etc?) If so, try clearing the cache.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't make sense that one site would reflect the changes and others wouldn't since they are all using the same theme files.

If you are using a caching plugin, try clearing it in the WP admin panel (either in the plugin options, or most popular caching plugins simply have an option to clear the cache in the WP admin bar you get at the top of the page when browsing it logged in).

If that isn't the problem, clear your browser's cache and try hard refreshing (Ctrl+F5) a few times on the sites where the theme css is not updating correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Add IMPORTANT property with your change like if you are going to change the height

then use like this

height:10px!important;

may be this works for you...